# (Java) Trying to load a clip from JAR file using getResourceAsStream(), but works only on my IDE

Tags: java, swing, jar

I'm trying to load a clip from my JAR file, but it only works in my IDE (NetBeans), and not when I run its JAR executable.

Here's the code I'm using that returns a clip:

```
public static Clip getClipFromJar(String filePath) {
    try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(FileLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(filePath)));
        return clip;
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.exit(-1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm really stuck, using getResourceAsStream() seemed to work for other things such as images, but it's not working for getting a clip.

Thanks for all the help everyone! The tips I got from you guys are good for programming in general, so thanks! :)

Comment: Change `} catch (Exception error) {` to `} catch (Exception error) { e.printStackTrace();`.  Right now, we can only guess why it is failing,  (I have a theory, but the stacktrace will either prove or disprove it.)

Comment: @MadProgrammer My filepath is set to "/Resources/bgm/title screen.wav"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the URL , take care of the `AudioInputStream` and `AudioSytem` and then return the `clip` . And the `clip` can be started like `clip.start()` after that

```
try{ 
    URL soundURL = getClass().getResource(filePath); 
    AudioInputStream AIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL); 
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
    clip.open(AIS);
    return clip;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note :** I tried this code and it worked properly both in IDE and outside

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. If it doesn't work for me, it's for sure a file mislocation on my end.

Comment: I'm using a static class, so I had to change getClass() to MyClass.class    It worked out fine though, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: close() the clip once you are done using it. It will free the resources . And it is really important if you are dealing with large files.

Comment: If i change the reference of the clip, I will still need to close() it right?

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceAsStream()` looks for its resource on the classpath, starting with the location of the class itself -- so if your clip (or whatever resource) is in the same folder as the class, it'll find it there.  If it isn't there, you have to make sure you have it in the classpath somewhere, and it sounds like that might be difference between your IDE environment and your program runtime.

Look at the 'filepath' you have also -- if it starts with a slash of course, it is absolute, etc.; I'm assuming you know about the absolute and relative paths.

A suggestion for debugging -- eliminate all the 'stacking' of calls.  Make one call to get the stream; make another call to get the audio input stream, and a third to open it.  Then you can at least put in trace statements to see which one of them is failing (since you can't debug outside of the IDE, and it isn't failing there).

Comment: @asdf In particular if it's supposed to be in the jar, look at the jar with `jar t` to make sure it *is* in the jar and with the pathname you are trying to open. Also if you get an exception it almost always contains useful information; don't throw it away, output it someplace you can look at it (possibly but not necessarily `System.out`).

Comment: @dave I'm not sure what jar t means, but I do know the sound file I'm trying to access is in the jar files (I used WinRAR to make sure of it).

Comment: @arcy Yup, I know the difference between absolute and relative paths.  Also, I'll keep the debugging thing in mind!  I've always tried to shorten my code if I could, but I guess it's not always the case. xD Thanks :)

Comment: 'Shortening' code -- if,f by that, you mean putting on one line what could also go in 3-4-8 lines -- should never be a goal by itself.  Code is read more often than it is written; it should be written so that it is easy to read.  If the one-line version is easier to read, good, but it rarely is even as easy.  And when you get a stacktrace, it can only tell you the line number, not which call on the line, threw the exception.  // We don't seem to have answered your question yet; dump your filepath and let us know what that is.

Comment: @asdf `jar` is the JDK utility program that does various operations on jar files like creating, modifying, extracting and listing controlled by options you specify; `t` is the option to list the contents of an existing jar. In other words, run the `jar` program with the `t` option on your jar file (which is specified with the `f` option), to see and confirm the (exact) name of the desired entry in the file.